# Transpile spread operators in `vue-cli` to support MS Edge

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, microsoft-edge

MS Edge doesn't support spread operators so I have to transpile them. I have quite a bit of dependencies so using `transpileDependencies` config option doesn't cut it since I don't know which dependencies are using `...` or if existing dependencies will add them in the future. How do I enable transpiling of just the `...` spread operator for my app?

Also, adding `vuetify` to the `transpileDependencies` list also causes this error when opening the app in the browser.

```
chunk-vendors.7720ff1c.js:96 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at Object.c0a4 (chunk-vendors.7720ff1c.js:96)
    at i (bootstrap:79)
    at Module.56d7 (app.235a86d4.js:11)
    at i (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (app.235a86d4.js:1)
    at i (bootstrap:79)
    at a (bootstrap:45)
    at bootstrap:152
    at app.235a86d4.js:1
```

**UPDATE**: It turns out I just needed to follow the [official documentation here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/browser-support).

Comment: You could try to install the `babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread`, then, add the following code in the configure file `{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}`. More detail information please check [@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread) and [Object spread operator with vue-cli](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/object-spread-operator-with-vue-cli/36651)